# Захват звука с (колонок) аудиовыхода

Tags: java, аудио

Привет всем, нужна помощь с захватом звука с аудио выхода (если это вообще возможно средствами Java) Данный код работает, но захватывает звук только с микрофонов как заставить его работать и с аудиовыходами?

```
try {

        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

        AudioFormat f = new AudioFormat(48000, 16, 2, true, false);
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, f);

        Mixer mixer0 = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]);

        TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer0.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        targetDataLine.open(f);
        targetDataLine.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

при выборе других микшеров вылетает

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 48000.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
```

Comment: Средствами Java вряд ли. Сторонними библиотеками думаю возможно. Посмотрите, например https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi -
 класс [AudioCaptureClient](http://apidocs.jitsi.org/libjitsi/index.html?org/jitsi/impl/neomedia/jmfext/media/protocol/wasapi/AudioCaptureClient.html) с параметром AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK позволяет задействовать режим WASAPI Looback (только в Windows, но думаю под другие платформы есть что-то аналогичное).

Comment: Спасибо, случайно нет ссылки с примером?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению.